# Can we create multiple instances of a Kubernetes cluster & access it through different external IPs?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

In Brief, I want to create multiple instances of a pod contains MongoDB & Mongo-express containers which can be accessed through different external IPs. Even when we change anything from mongo-express GUI then the change should be reflected into that particular instance's Mongo database not others. That means, each instance should create a separate volume also.

My current YAML code is below: (Now it creates a single instance only and can be access through the localhost)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-configmap
data:
  database_url: mongodb-service
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongodb-statefulset
spec:
  serviceName: "mongodb-service"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env:
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
            value: "admin"
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: "pass"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongo-initdb
          mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: mongo-initdb
        configMap:
          name: mongo-initdb
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
      protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      hostname: mongo-express
      subdomain: mongodb-service
      containers:
      # Container for Mongo-Service
      - name: mongo-express
        image: mongo-express
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        env:
          - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
            value: "admin"
          - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
            value: "pass"
          - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
            valueFrom: 
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-configmap
                key: database_url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      protocol: TCP
      name: port1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create multiple instances of a cluster, you just need 2 instances of your application. Essentially, two copies of your application that will be isolated in different namespaces, and both will be reachable from the outside through `externalIP`.

Let's call these namespaces `instance-1` and `instance-2`. This way, you can even use same resource names. It will work for pods because their IP addresses will be different since the internal DNS name uses `namespace` as one of the parameters. E-g `mongo-express-service.instance1` will be a different DNS name than `mongo-express-service.instance2`. And it will be different for `ConfigMaps` because they are namespaced as well, you can have the same name if you want in both namespaces. Same true for your `Deployment` and `StatefulSet`.

That being said, you can very easily set an `externalIP` on your `LoadBalancer` type service (mongo-express) by adding the following field to your `Service` manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      protocol: TCP
      name: port1
  externalIPs:
    - 0.0.0.0 #<======= CHANGE_ME
```

Simply create two separate namespaces:

```
kubectl create namespace instance-1
kubectl create namespace instance-2
```

Then configure the right `externalIP` field for each service. E-g

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      protocol: TCP
      name: port1
  externalIPs:
    - 1.1.1.1 #<======= CHANGE_ME
```

and for your second instance

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      protocol: TCP
      name: port1
  externalIPs:
    - 2.2.2.2 #<======= CHANGE_ME
```

Now, let's assume you will have 2 copies of your YAML file, first one, `my-application-1.yaml` which will have `externalIP` set to `1.1.1.1` and all other resources the same. Another one called `my-application-2.yaml` with `externalIP` set to `2.2.2.2` and all the rest of the resources the same.

Now you can apply all components of your application once to your `instance-1` namespace.

```
# Assuming this is the service with externalIP 1.1.1.1
kubectl apply -n instance-1 my-application-1.yaml
```

And the same components, with modified `externalIP` to another namespace:

```
# Assuming this is the service with externalIP 2.2.2.2
kubectl apply -n instance-2 my-application-2.yaml
```

Now you can reach your services easily on external IPs at the endpoints:

```
1.1.1.1:8081 # This is instance 1
2.2.2.2:8081 # This is instance 2
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I am not able to access it through that external IP. It's only accessible through local host. But when I am executing the "kubectl get service" command then in the External-IP column and Load Balancer row its shows "localhost, 192.168.1.2". Is there anything I'm missing? (I have added 192.168.1.2  as externalIPs in YAML file )

Comment: You might have to remove the localhost entry from externalIP field. You can simply `kubectl edit` the service and do that.